# Electron / Linux : Give fullscreen back to previous application

Tags: javascript, linux, electron, fullscreen

I'm using electron in webpages (`BrowserWindow`).

I use this in the first page :

```
MyWin = new BrowserWindow({show: false, fullscreen: true})
MyWin.loadURL('webpage.html');
MyWin.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
MyWin.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  MyWin.show();
  MyWin.focus();
})
```

And in the `webpage.html`, i use :

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
window.close();
```

My problem is that if I have for example video player `mpv` in fullscreen, the `webpage.html` appears fullscreen as well. (Which is fine.)

But fullscreen is not given back to my video player when `webpage.html` is closed...

How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's more related to your linux desktop environment reather than electron itself. If you can, you could try to simulate the fullscreen behaviour by setting the size of your BrowserWindow according to your screen resolution.

```
 const { width, height } = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
 win = new BrowserWindow({ width, height, fullscreen: false })
```

Comment: thx for the interest, but using this it just appears behind the video player.

Comment: So i tried on a fresh install of `cinnamon` and yes you were right ! The code works like a charm. So I now need to figure out why it doesn't work on my `i3`. Thanks !!!

Comment: I don't really know i3 and how it works. Probably i3 can't handle the "alwaysontop" setting. The browserwindow was on top only thanks to the fullscreen option. But I repeat, it's only an hypothesis

Comment: I solved the issue using a mpv socket system script (detect if fullscreen and give it back). But it seems on i3 that electron is stealing the fullscreen from other applications. Strange because I had other fullscreen systems that worked well with i3. Maybe an incompatibility between i3 and electron...